# NHibernate - Query misses the query cache after saving a new entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have NHibernate (with [NHibernate.Linq](http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Linq) and [Fluent NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/)) set up with query caching. Everything works fine until I do a `session.Save(new Widget())` (i.e. SQL `INSERT`). After that point, all queries on that type `Widget` miss the query cache. Queries on other entity types are cached just fine.

```
using (ISession session = MySessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // this INSERT screws things up
        var widget = new Widget {Name = "Foo"};
        session.Save(widget);

        var query = (from w in session.Query<Widget>().Cacheable()
                     where w.Name == "Bar"
                     select w);

        var fetched1 = query.FirstOrDefault();
        var fetched2 = query.FirstOrDefault(); // miss?!

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

If I start a new `Transaction`, the problem persists. If I start a new `Session`, the problem goes away. This seems kind of strange, since my understanding was the second level cache gets reset per `SessionFactory` (not `Session`).

I don't think this matters, but I am using the `HashtableCacheProvider`, since I'm just testing right now.

Comment: what error was occurred sir?

Comment: It's not an error in the sense that exception was thrown. Rather, the second query (`var fetched2 = query.FirstOrDefault();`) skips the query cache and directly hits the database (which is not the expected behavior).

Comment: Have you enabled the query cache? I think you have to do that separately from the entity cache.

Comment: Yes. Before doing a `session.Save(...)`, the query caching works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour you've described is correct *([more here](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate))*.

> The update timestamp cache is not updated until you commit the
>   transaction! This is to ensure that you will not read "uncommitted
>   values" from the cache.

Whenever there is a change on a `type` which we've got in Cache - cached data are stale... until the complete transaction is commited.

Imagine that you've cached results of this filter:

```
 var query = (from w in session.Query<Widget>().Cacheable()
  where w.Name == "B*" // all names starting with B
  select w);
```

And later will add new Widget:

```
var widget = new Widget {Name = "Brigitte"};
session.Save(widget);
// explicit Flush is not needed, 
// but then, until Commit(), query will never return Brigitte
session.Flush(); // to immediately execute INSERT
```

If the query would be still cached, Brigitte will never appear...

And while in Transaction, queries with FirstOrDefault() are executed immediately - the write operations could wait for a Flush on Commit.

Because of the Transaction, all contained operations (insert, udpate, select) cannot profit from caching, because only Transaction as a batch makes sense. So until commit is called, no cache could be used.

Many detailed and very helpful information could be found here: [First and Second Level caching in NHibernate](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate)

> The timestamp cache is updated whenever a table is written to, but in a tricky sort of way:
>
> - When we perform the actual writing, we write a value that is somewhere in the future to the cache. So all queries that hit the
>     cache now will not find it, and then hit the DB to get the new data.
>     Since we are in the middle of transaction, they would wait until we
>     finish the transaction. If we are using low isolation level, and
>     another thread / machine attempts to put the old results back in the
>     cache, it wouldn't hold, because the update timestamp is into the
>     future.
> - When we perform the commit on the transaction, we update the timestamp cache with the current value.